# Is there a way to stop an ajax process in case there is an error with PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter-3

I have a problem with Firefox 45. It's always saying `$_FILES['imagem']` is undefined and is `null`, even having images already previously selected and shown from the database. Only in version 45, which I believe to be a bug.

The editing process is called via Ajax, and thank to this error, the ajax keeps loading forever. I'd like to know if there's a way to stop its process and show an error in the view.

```
$FILES = $_FILES;
$count = count($_FILES['imagem']['name']) - 2;

for ($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++) {
    $_FILES['imagem']['name'] = $FILES['imagem']['name'][$i];
    $_FILES['imagem']['name'] = $FILES['imagem']['name'][$i];
    $_FILES['imagem']['type'] = $FILES['imagem']['type'][$i];
    $_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'] = $FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $_FILES['imagem']['error'] = $FILES['imagem']['error'][$i];
    $_FILES['imagem']['size'] = $FILES['imagem']['size'][$i];

    if (isset($_FILES['imagem']) && $_FILES['imagem']['name'] !== '') {
        $config['file_name'] = $id . '_' . $_FILES['imagem']['name'];
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/carros/imagens/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png';
        $config['overwrite'] = true;

        $imagem = array();
        $imagem['id_carro'] = $id;
        $imagem['imagem'] = $config['file_name'];

        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        $this->upload->do_upload('imagem');
        $this->Imagens_carro_model->insert($imagem);
    }

    //
    // Apagar caso haja.
    if ($this->input->post('nome_imagem')[$i] === '') {
        $this->Imagens_carro_model->delete($this->input->post('id_imagem')[$i]);
    }
}
```

Above is part of the code where the error is generated:

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: imagem
>
> Filename: controllers/Carros.php
>
> Line Number: 161
>
> ...

I guess I can't do anything with `error` because it actually succeeds, and the error occurs in PHP part, when it didn't find `imagem` index. Suggestions?

Comment: I'm questioning your PHP code. What are you even trying to do with assigning `$_FILES` to `$FILES` and overwriting `$_FILES`?

Comment: You can use `if (isset($_FILES['imagem']))` in the PHP.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois For some reason, if I don't do it, an error saying `is_uploaded_file()` expects one parameter is thrown, although it will upload the image, but the ajax will stuck at the loading.

Answer (score 0):

You may check the response if you send a curated response from your `PHP`, for example, on a successful operation send a `json` response like (This might not be the accurate answer to the question but an idea to help the `OP` with `ajax` error handling ideas):

```
if(somethingWasSuccessfull) {
    $response = [
        'success' => true,
        'message' => 'something was successful!'
    ];
}
else {
    $response = [
        'success' => false,
        'message' => 'something was not successful!'
    ];
}

echo json_encode(($response);
```

So, when you recieve the response on `done/success` callback on your client side you can check the value of `success`, for example:

```
$.ajax(...)
.done(function(response) {
    // Request succeeded
    // Probably parse the response
    if(response.success) {
        // Successfull, status code is 200
    }
    else {
        // Not successfull, status code is 200
    }
})
.fail(function(response) {
    // Error happened..., status code is not 200
})
.always(function(response) {
    // Perform some common tasks
});
```